# Alternate to dynamic allocation of memory?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am submitting my code on one of the Online Judges. My program is accepted.
However, some part of my program requires a **long integer array of atmost 10,000 elements**. Size is entered by the judge during runtime.
I dynamically allocate memory using:

```
int *array = new int[size];
```

But this eats lots of time during runtime. My execution time is bad, resulting in a bad rank.
Is there possibly any **FASTER alternate to dynamic allocation** considering requirements of the program?

I don't know why but creating an array statically (which I think is a bad idea) using

```
int array[10000];
```

gives me a **"Runtime error (access violation)"**

PS : I am just a beginner.

Comment: Are you sure the allocation is whats taking up most of the execution time?

Comment: Have you measured the time of your whole program and the time of the allocation (new int[size]) ?

Comment: If I allocate memory statically, my program is successfully handles 10 test cases with execution time 0.015 s but memory allocation makes it 0.125 s.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation is a comparably cheap operation. Unless you're doing it a zillion times in a row, this is hardly where your performance bottleneck is. Unless of course, you're allocating so much memory that it requires constant swapping to disk, but I doubt an application for a contest will require to use that much memory.

Answer (score 0):

10000 long ints is actually not much memory for modern computers. You should be able to allocate hundred times more in milisecons on any personal computer.

However, runtime error, which you get when allocating statically, means, that probably your program tries to use more than 10000 values from array. Therefore, maybe judge allocates more than 10000-size array in dynamic allocation?

Try making a static array of bigger size (remember that a milion longs is just a few megabytes) and check if runtime error still occurs